# How to create a stronger blur in FabricJS?

Tags: html, canvas

I am uploading an image onto a canvas using FabricJS and I would like to blur it. Looking at the examples on their [site](http://fabricjs.com/image-filters/) I can create a light blur. However, I would like to make this blur stronger. Essentially I would like to make this stronger blur and then have text on top. I am thinking I need to adjust the convolution matrix but I am not certain how to go about that.

Any hints?

PS. I would upload a Fiddle but because of canvas and CORS image issue it would not be useful :(

Comment: Maybe apply the blur multiple times to create a stronger blur?

Comment: Good thought but the problem with that is it takes a long time :(. I tried it out :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I solved this issue is to make the filter bigger and denser (I'm not completely sure how it works but it does the job, still looking for a ELI5 in the future).

The box blur outputs the average of the pixel values inside the convolution matrix. The way to do that is to create a convolution matrix of size NxN where each of the weights is 1 / (NxN). That way each of the pixels inside the matrix contributes an equal amount to the output image and the sum of the weights is one 
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/

**Matrix**

```
    // weak convolution filter box blur
    [ 1/9, 1/9, 1/9,
      1/9, 1/9, 1/9,
      1/9, 1/9, 1/9 ]
```

**Output**

[image]

**Matrix**

```
    // stronger convolution filter box blur
    [ 1/18, 1/18, 1/18,
      1/18, 1/18, 1/18,
      1/18, 1/18, 1/18,
      1/18, 1/18, 1/18,
      1/18, 1/18, 1/18,
      1/18, 1/18, 1/18 ]
```

**Output**

[image]

**Matrix**

```
    // strong convolution filter box blur
    [ 1/27, 1/27, 1/27,
      1/27, 1/27, 1/27,
      1/27, 1/27, 1/27,
      1/27, 1/27, 1/27,
      1/27, 1/27, 1/27,
      1/27, 1/27, 1/27,
      1/27, 1/27, 1/27,
      1/27, 1/27, 1/27,
      1/27, 1/27, 1/27 ]
```

**Output**

[image]

**Matrix**

```
    // super strong convolution filter box blur
    [ 1/36, 1/36, 1/36,
      1/36, 1/36, 1/36,
      1/36, 1/36, 1/36,
      1/36, 1/36, 1/36,
      1/36, 1/36, 1/36,
      1/36, 1/36, 1/36,
      1/36, 1/36, 1/36,
      1/36, 1/36, 1/36,
      1/36, 1/36, 1/36,
      1/36, 1/36, 1/36,
      1/36, 1/36, 1/36,
      1/36, 1/36, 1/36 ]
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my gist here:
https://gist.github.com/human-a/25b7f58565b89de4e999ef2f4de1982c

```
/**
 * Stack blur filter for fabricjs
 * Example:
 * obj.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.StackBlur(6));
 * obj.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
 *
 * Heavily inspired by:
 * https://gist.github.com/pierrickouw/2ab679159beee9d80ca6
 * http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html
 * uses stackBlurCanvasRGBA function but could be swapped be stackBlurCanvasRGB
 * @see: http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlur.js
 */

(function() {

    var fabric  = window.fabric,
    extend = fabric.util.object.extend;

    var mul_table = [
    512,512,456,512,328,456,335,512,405,328,271,456,388,335,292,512,
    454,405,364,328,298,271,496,456,420,388,360,335,312,292,273,512,
    482,454,428,405,383,364,345,328,312,298,284,271,259,496,475,456,
    437,420,404,388,374,360,347,335,323,312,302,292,282,273,265,512,
    497,482,468,454,441,428,417,405,394,383,373,364,354,345,337,328,
    320,312,305,298,291,284,278,271,265,259,507,496,485,475,465,456,
    446,437,428,420,412,404,396,388,381,374,367,360,354,347,341,335,
    329,323,318,312,307,302,297,292,287,282,278,273,269,265,261,512,
    505,497,489,482,475,468,461,454,447,441,435,428,422,417,411,405,
    399,394,389,383,378,373,368,364,359,354,350,345,341,337,332,328,
    324,320,316,312,309,305,301,298,294,291,287,284,281,278,274,271,
    268,265,262,259,257,507,501,496,491,485,480,475,470,465,460,456,
    451,446,442,437,433,428,424,420,416,412,408,404,400,396,392,388,
    385,381,377,374,370,367,363,360,357,354,350,347,344,341,338,335,
    332,329,326,323,320,318,315,312,310,307,304,302,299,297,294,292,
    289,287,285,282,280,278,275,273,271,269,267,265,263,261,259
    ];
    var shg_table = [
    9, 11, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17,
    17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19,
    19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20,
    20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21,
    21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21,
    21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22,
    22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22,
    22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 23,
    23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23,
    23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23,
    23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23,
    23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24,
    24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24,
    24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24,
    24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24,
    24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24
    ];

    function BlurStack() {
        this.r = 0;
        this.g = 0;
        this.b = 0;
        this.a = 0;
        this.next = null;
    }

    fabric.Image.filters.StackBlur = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Image.filters.BaseFilter,{

        /**
        * Filter type
        */
        type: 'StackBlur',

        /**
        * Constructor
        */
        initialize: function(radius) { //radius of the blur
            this.radius = radius || 0;
            if(this.radius > 180) {
                this.radius = 180;
            }

            if(this.radius < 1) {
                this.radius = 0;
            }
        },

        /**
        * Applies blur to canvas element
        */
        applyTo: function(canvas) {
            // Don't apply blur if it's zero
            if (!this.radius) return;

            var radius = this.radius;
            var width = canvas.width;
            var height = canvas.height;
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var imageData;

            imageData = context.getImageData( 0, 0, width, height );

            var pixels = imageData.data;

            var x, y, i, p, yp, yi, yw, r_sum, g_sum, b_sum, a_sum,
                r_out_sum, g_out_sum, b_out_sum, a_out_sum,
                r_in_sum, g_in_sum, b_in_sum, a_in_sum,
                pr, pg, pb, pa, rbs;

            var div = radius + radius + 1;
            var widthMinus1  = width - 1;
            var heightMinus1 = height - 1;
            var radiusPlus1  = radius + 1;
            var sumFactor = radiusPlus1 * ( radiusPlus1 + 1 ) / 2;

            var stackStart = new BlurStack();
            var stack = stackStart;
            for ( i = 1; i < div; i++ ) {
                stack = stack.next = new BlurStack();
                if ( i === radiusPlus1 ) var stackEnd = stack;
            }
            stack.next = stackStart;
            var stackIn = null;
            var stackOut = null;

            yw = yi = 0;

            var mul_sum = mul_table[radius];
            var shg_sum = shg_table[radius];

            for ( y = 0; y < height; y++ ) {
                r_in_sum = g_in_sum = b_in_sum = a_in_sum = r_sum = g_sum = b_sum = a_sum = 0;

                r_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * ( pr = pixels[yi] );
                g_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * ( pg = pixels[yi+1] );
                b_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * ( pb = pixels[yi+2] );
                a_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * ( pa = pixels[yi+3] );

                r_sum += sumFactor * pr;
                g_sum += sumFactor * pg;
                b_sum += sumFactor * pb;
                a_sum += sumFactor * pa;

                stack = stackStart;

                for( i = 0; i < radiusPlus1; i++ ) {
                    stack.r = pr;
                    stack.g = pg;
                    stack.b = pb;
                    stack.a = pa;
                    stack = stack.next;
                }

                for( i = 1; i < radiusPlus1; i++ ) {
                    p = yi + (( widthMinus1 < i ? widthMinus1 : i ) << 2 );
                    r_sum += ( stack.r = ( pr = pixels[p])) * ( rbs = radiusPlus1 - i );
                    g_sum += ( stack.g = ( pg = pixels[p+1])) * rbs;
                    b_sum += ( stack.b = ( pb = pixels[p+2])) * rbs;
                    a_sum += ( stack.a = ( pa = pixels[p+3])) * rbs;

                    r_in_sum += pr;
                    g_in_sum += pg;
                    b_in_sum += pb;
                    a_in_sum += pa;

                    stack = stack.next;
                }


                stackIn = stackStart;
                stackOut = stackEnd;
                for ( x = 0; x < width; x++ ) {
                    pixels[yi+3] = pa = (a_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum;
                    if ( pa !== 0 )
                    {
                        pa = 255 / pa;
                        pixels[yi]   = ((r_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum) * pa;
                        pixels[yi+1] = ((g_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum) * pa;
                        pixels[yi+2] = ((b_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum) * pa;
                    } else {
                        pixels[yi] = pixels[yi+1] = pixels[yi+2] = 0;
                    }

                    r_sum -= r_out_sum;
                    g_sum -= g_out_sum;
                    b_sum -= b_out_sum;
                    a_sum -= a_out_sum;

                    r_out_sum -= stackIn.r;
                    g_out_sum -= stackIn.g;
                    b_out_sum -= stackIn.b;
                    a_out_sum -= stackIn.a;

                    // eslint-disable-next-line
                    p = ( yw + ( ( p = x + radius + 1 ) < widthMinus1 ? p : widthMinus1 ) ) << 2;

                    r_in_sum += ( stackIn.r = pixels[p]);
                    g_in_sum += ( stackIn.g = pixels[p+1]);
                    b_in_sum += ( stackIn.b = pixels[p+2]);
                    a_in_sum += ( stackIn.a = pixels[p+3]);

                    r_sum += r_in_sum;
                    g_sum += g_in_sum;
                    b_sum += b_in_sum;
                    a_sum += a_in_sum;

                    stackIn = stackIn.next;

                    r_out_sum += ( pr = stackOut.r );
                    g_out_sum += ( pg = stackOut.g );
                    b_out_sum += ( pb = stackOut.b );
                    a_out_sum += ( pa = stackOut.a );

                    r_in_sum -= pr;
                    g_in_sum -= pg;
                    b_in_sum -= pb;
                    a_in_sum -= pa;

                    stackOut = stackOut.next;

                    yi += 4;
                }
                yw += width;
            }


            for ( x = 0; x < width; x++ ) {
                g_in_sum = b_in_sum = a_in_sum = r_in_sum = g_sum = b_sum = a_sum = r_sum = 0;

                yi = x << 2;
                r_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * ( pr = pixels[yi]);
                g_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * ( pg = pixels[yi+1]);
                b_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * ( pb = pixels[yi+2]);
                a_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * ( pa = pixels[yi+3]);

                r_sum += sumFactor * pr;
                g_sum += sumFactor * pg;
                b_sum += sumFactor * pb;
                a_sum += sumFactor * pa;

                stack = stackStart;

                for( i = 0; i < radiusPlus1; i++ )
                {
                    stack.r = pr;
                    stack.g = pg;
                    stack.b = pb;
                    stack.a = pa;
                    stack = stack.next;
                }

                yp = width;

                for( i = 1; i <= radius; i++ )
                {
                    yi = ( yp + x ) << 2;

                    r_sum += ( stack.r = ( pr = pixels[yi])) * ( rbs = radiusPlus1 - i );
                    g_sum += ( stack.g = ( pg = pixels[yi+1])) * rbs;
                    b_sum += ( stack.b = ( pb = pixels[yi+2])) * rbs;
                    a_sum += ( stack.a = ( pa = pixels[yi+3])) * rbs;

                    r_in_sum += pr;
                    g_in_sum += pg;
                    b_in_sum += pb;
                    a_in_sum += pa;

                    stack = stack.next;

                    if( i < heightMinus1 )
                    {
                        yp += width;
                    }
                }

                yi = x;
                stackIn = stackStart;
                stackOut = stackEnd;
                for ( y = 0; y < height; y++ )
                {
                    p = yi << 2;
                    pixels[p+3] = pa = (a_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum;
                    if ( pa > 0 )
                    {
                        pa = 255 / pa;
                        pixels[p]   = ((r_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum ) * pa;
                        pixels[p+1] = ((g_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum ) * pa;
                        pixels[p+2] = ((b_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum ) * pa;
                    } else {
                        pixels[p] = pixels[p+1] = pixels[p+2] = 0;
                    }

                    r_sum -= r_out_sum;
                    g_sum -= g_out_sum;
                    b_sum -= b_out_sum;
                    a_sum -= a_out_sum;

                    r_out_sum -= stackIn.r;
                    g_out_sum -= stackIn.g;
                    b_out_sum -= stackIn.b;
                    a_out_sum -= stackIn.a;

                    // eslint-disable-next-line
                    p = ( x + (( ( p = y + radiusPlus1) < heightMinus1 ? p : heightMinus1 ) * width )) << 2;

                    r_sum += ( r_in_sum += ( stackIn.r = pixels[p]));
                    g_sum += ( g_in_sum += ( stackIn.g = pixels[p+1]));
                    b_sum += ( b_in_sum += ( stackIn.b = pixels[p+2]));
                    a_sum += ( a_in_sum += ( stackIn.a = pixels[p+3]));

                    stackIn = stackIn.next;

                    r_out_sum += ( pr = stackOut.r );
                    g_out_sum += ( pg = stackOut.g );
                        b_out_sum += ( pb = stackOut.b );
                        a_out_sum += ( pa = stackOut.a );

                        r_in_sum -= pr;
                        g_in_sum -= pg;
                        b_in_sum -= pb;
                        a_in_sum -= pa;

                        stackOut = stackOut.next;

                        yi += width;
                    }
                }
            context.putImageData( imageData, 0, 0 );

        },

        /**
        * Returns object representation of an instance
        */
        toObject: function() {
            return extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {
                radius: this.radius
            });
        }
    });

    // fabric.Image.filters.StackBlur.fromObject = function(object) {
        // return new fabric.Image.filters.StackBlur(object);
    // };

    // Edit: if you wish to save your canvas and retrieve it later it's better to use the following:
    fabric.Image.filters.StackBlur.fromObject = fabric.Image.filters.BaseFilter.fromObject;

})()
```

This code works perfectly fine when you want to add blur to images, you can increase or decrease the blur amount too, just like you would with the native brightness filter.

**EDIT:** If you wish to save your canvas and retrieve it later it's better to use the following:

```
fabric.Image.filters.StackBlur.fromObject = fabric.Image.filters.BaseFilter.fromObject;
```

Same fix is now applied to the gist.

Comment: This is awesome bro..works better than the code you were inspired by. thank you